# Unable to set the layout as expected using Bootstrap v4 alpha 6

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap v4 alpha 6` and I'm trying to design a card that is similar to the layout on this [site](https://clutch.co/agencies). I've created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8WE8AGPloEkh6s4jCs8?p=preview) to demo my problem. Here is a pic of what I am trying to create

[image]

The issue is occurs when I add a row to (`col-6`) and try splitting that row into 3 equal sized columns unlike the [clutch.io](https://clutch.co/agencies) site the columns on my [page](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8WE8AGPloEkh6s4jCs8?p=preview) fold into 3 separate rows if the content in them is too long. Instead of that I would like to expand the column vertically if the content is too long.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let sc of scs?.data">
  <div class="col-9">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-block">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="row" style="border-bottom: 2px solid;">
            <img class="d-flex mr-3 imgLogo float-left" [src]="storageURL + sc.imageURL" width="180" height="150">
            <h4>{{sc.company}}</h4>
          </div>
         <!-- Here is the second row which I would like to split into 3 columns-->
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              hiasdasdasdl;aksd;laksjdlakjsd;alskjd;alskjd;alksjd;lakjsdl;aksjdlasjkdlakjsd
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              hiasdlkjasdljasldjalsdkadl
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              hilakjsdlaksdjlaskjdlaksdjlaskj
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <div class="row">
            View Website
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            View Profile
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            Message
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br class="mb-3"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not clear at all what you want. try to explain it better.

Comment: Hi sorry about that. I've updated my OP does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

Use a class for these columns that restricts their width, like `col-sm-3` or `col-sm-4`:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpjJWm